# Where do I find prestige classes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, product-identification

I have several prestige classes that I want to try but I don't know in which books they are printed. Can you please tell me? I would like to try Shadowdancer, Airship Pilot, Arcane Drummer, and Gunslinger.

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia actually has a page that seems to list *all* of them and their locations: [List of prestige classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prestige_classes).